# Bluetooth mouse cannot connect

Tags: bluetooth

This is what I see in bluetoothctl:

```
[bluetooth]# pair 11:21:EC:00:00:02
Attempting to pair with 11:21:EC:00:00:02
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists
[bluetooth]# trust 11:21:EC:00:00:02
Changing 11:21:EC:00:00:02 trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# connect 11:21:EC:00:00:02
Attempting to connect to 11:21:EC:00:00:02
[CHG] Device 11:21:EC:00:00:02 Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-create-socket
[CHG] Device 11:21:EC:00:00:02 Connected: no
```

The mouse was working yesterday, today it doesn't.

If I turn off and on the mouse (while bluetoothctl is running) multiple times, then I see this:

```
[CHG] Device 11:21:EC:00:00:02 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 11:21:EC:00:00:02 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 11:21:EC:00:00:02 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 11:21:EC:00:00:02 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 11:21:EC:00:00:02 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 11:21:EC:00:00:02 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 11:21:EC:00:00:02 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 11:21:EC:00:00:02 Connected: no
[bluetooth]#
```

So first it connects, but then immediatelly disconnects.

If I try to manually connect (by tying in "connect MAC" from bluetoothctl) then I see this in syslog:

```
Sep 26 10:15:53 vivobook-linux bluetoothd[7134]: profiles/input/device.c:ioctl_is_connected() Can't get HIDP connection info
Sep 26 10:15:59 vivobook-linux bluetoothd[7134]: profiles/input/device.c:control_connect_cb() connect to 11:21:EC:00:00:02: Host is down (112)
```

It says that host is down, but in reality it is not down.

It doesn't help if I put the mouse into pairing mode either.

**UPDATE** here is the output from btmon:

```
$ sudo btmon -w pair.bts
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.64
= Note: Linux version 6.2.0-33-generic (x86_64)                                                                                                                    0.286424
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                                                                                                                           0.286427
= New Index: AC:12:03:3C:0C:CA (Primary,USB,hci0)                                                                                                           [hci0] 0.286430
= Open Index: AC:12:03:3C:0C:CA                                                                                                                             [hci0] 0.286431
= Index Info: AC:12:03:3C:0C:CA (Intel Corp.)                                                                                                               [hci0] 0.286434
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.22                                                                                                         {0x0001} 0.286436
= bluetoothd: profiles/input/device.c:ioctl_is_connected() Can't get HIDP connection info                                                                         20.303463
< HCI Command: Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) plen 13                                                                                                  #1 [hci0] 20.303511
        Address: 11:21:EC:00:00:02 (OUI 11-21-EC)
        Packet type: 0xcc18
          DM1 may be used
          DH1 may be used
          DM3 may be used
          DH3 may be used
          DM5 may be used
          DH5 may be used
        Page scan repetition mode: R2 (0x02)
        Page scan mode: Mandatory (0x00)
        Clock offset: 0x0000
        Role switch: Allow peripheral (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                                               #2 [hci0] 20.428572
      Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Connect Complete (0x03) plen 11                                                                                                            #3 [hci0] 25.645679
        Status: Page Timeout (0x04)
        Handle: 65535
        Address: 11:21:EC:00:00:02 (OUI 11-21-EC)
        Link type: ACL (0x01)
        Encryption: Disabled (0x00)
@ MGMT Event: Connect Failed (0x000d) plen 8                                                                                                      {0x0001} [hci0] 25.645771
        BR/EDR Address: 11:21:EC:00:00:02 (OUI 11-21-EC)
        Status: Connect Failed (0x04)
= bluetoothd: profiles/input/device.c:control_connect_cb() connect to 11:21:EC:00:00:02: Host is down (112)                                                       25.646297
```

Comment: Just to be sure: the mouse's battery isn't low?

Comment: It is working under windows. So there is probably no problem with the mouse itself.

Comment: I cannot understand the output of btmon either. First it tells that connect is complete then it is failed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could make it work this way

- remove 11:21:EC:00:00:02
- turn off mouse
- turn on mouse again, put into pairing mode
- bluetoothctl scan on
- trust 11:21:EC:00:00:02
- pair 11:21:EC:00:00:02
- connect 11:21:EC:00:00:02

I'm not sure why, but I had to completely remove the device and add again. Not it works.